Suggestion for training various models for classification of different species
Working on developing classification networks for various types harmful algae vs algae/other objects found in the ocean water. We have developed binary networks for some harmful algae vs Ocean. There are over 5000 categories of these harmful algaes. Some of our customers require 5 harmful algae classification while others might require many more. What is the best way to develop machine learning solution for this problem ? Any suggestion is appreciated.
Approach 1: We could train the multiclass model for customers requirement. Lets say customer is interested in A, B, and C harmful algae Vs Rest (Ocean + remaining harmful algae.) But this will require lot of data and training for every combination of these species. Is there any better way ?

I don't know whether we can help you without a lot more information (to the point that this might become a consulting project). But overall, yes, if you need to classify into one of many categories, then you will need a lot of training data, that's just the way it works. You might be able to combine some of your customers' models: if they all have one common class A, then apply all models to one sample, and average the different probabilistic predictions for the sample to be A. This might improve matters.
